# Increase width but still center

Tags: html, css

I'm currently working on a form on my webpage in HTML, but I want to increase the width of input types (`name`, `e-mail`, `comment`). If I do so, for example:`width 200%`, it only increases on the right, but stays the same on the left.

Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: Provide code (what you've tried) and optionally a screenshot then we might be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't have any code posted. I would guess.
give you form tag width and margin: 0 auto; 
It should keep it in center

`<form style="width:70%; margin:0 auto;">
<input type="text" style="width:50%"/> 
</form>`

Comment: This is what I was searching for!  Thx Harry.